# Break points stopped breaking the code execution Delphi Embarcadero studio 10.2

Tags: delphi, ide, breakpoints

I work with Embarcadero Studio 10.2.

To do a debug I'm using break points. Somehow program doesn't stop at those break points any more.
The points are just marked with green tick but do not stop program execution.

In advanced properties of the breakpoint it is marked "break".

I tried to look through "project-options-Delphi Compiler", everything looks marked ok. I attach the screenshot.

Really appreciate some help! [image]

Comment: What build config is active, Debug or Release?

Comment: It is Debug  mode

Comment: Did you tried doing a "clean" and then "build" of your application (Debug config active)?

Comment: Yes, I did this as well. Also saved the project after this, got out completely from ide and entered again

Comment: Make sure a zombie / orphan instance of the program you are trying to debug isn't still running in the background. Rare but has happened to me in the past.

Comment: Always reboot your system when trying to clear this problem.  Then, after doing a full build or your project, if the breakpoint hasn't reverted to being displayed red, rather than green, try typing an exclamation mark into the source where the bp is.  If the compiler doesn't complain when you next do a compile, that tells you that the compiler is finding a different version of the unit that you think it is.

Comment: Are the blue dots correctly aligned with your code? Otherwise, problems with CR/LF are usually the cause.

Comment: @MartynA The idea of rebooting system worked! Thanks! Looks like the issue with another Windows update. Until I did it, the reboot didn't fix the problem/

Comment: I'm glad to hear that and will post my comment as an answer so that the q can be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup should always reboot your system when trying to clear this problem.

Then, after doing a full build or your project, if the breakpoint hasn't reverted to being displayed red, rather than green, try typing an exclamation mark into the source where the bp is. If the compiler doesn't complain when you next do a compile, that tells you that the compiler is finding a different version of the unit that you think it is.

Btw, the same cause - the compiler finding a different version of the unit that you think it is - can also result in breakpoints being mis-aligned vertically with the source, so that some b.p.s being on blank or irrelevant lines in the source.

Also btw, these sort of problems with breakpoints do not happen in source files which are explicitly listed amongst you project's source files in the Project Manager, because the compiler does not search around for the file.